# Make the computer hibernate automatically at certain times

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

I am looking for solution to make computer auto hibernate on specific time. Actually i have eletricity problem in my city and power goes after each hour. so i want computer auto hibernate on 1:55PM, 2:55PM, 3:55PM, 4:55PM, 5:55PM.

When its 0.55AM/PM in clock it should hibernate. Every hours: 55 minutes it should hibernate becuase power go on time. When its 12:00 power go, when its 2:00 power go and so on so i want it to do this each hour so that i can save my work!

Anyone know how to do this? Any software or windows schedule task?

**Additional Information.**

In my city power goes after each hour. means morning at: 7:00AM to Next Morning 7:00AM (12 hours load shedding)

```
7:00AM to 8:00AM
9:00AM to 10:00AM
11:00AM to 12:00PM
1:00PM to 2:00PM
3:00PM to 4:00PM
5:00PM to 6:00PM
7:00PM to 8:00PM
9:00PM to 10:00PM
11:00PM to 12:00PM
and so on to 7:00AM
```

So it would be best if computer hibernate at time:55 Minutes each hour.

Comment: It seems you live in a third-world country or some other region where the electrical system cannot provide power for everyone at the same time. Have you considered getting a UPS?

Comment: Well, UPS will cost alot so i am looking for some good and cheap solution

Answer (score 5):

If you execute the command `shutdown /h` it will cause Windows to hibernate. You can use the task scheduler to set this up on a regular schedule.

More information for the shutdown command is available [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732503.aspx).

Comment: I want it to hibernate not shutdown sir! And this will work for every hour? at :55?

Comment: shutdown with the /h after it is hibernate.  Just use it with task scheduler.

Comment: @poweruser, you confused this with the `shutdown /s` command, which fully shuts down the computer. Yozomin is correct.